# Create a VIEW with null value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, view, null

I'm trying to create a view in MySQL by joining 2 tables like this:

**Users** table:

```
+----+------+  
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Joy  |
+----+------+
| 2  | Roy  |
+----+------+
| 3  | Tony |
+----+------+
```

**Skills** table:

```
+---------+---------+------------+
| auto_id | user_id | skill      |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 1       | 1       | PHP        |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 2       | 1       | CSS        |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 3       | 2       | Ruby       |
+---------+---------+------------+
| 4       | 2       | Javascript |
+---------+---------+------------+
```

Here `user_id` in **Skills** table is the **Foreign key** of `id` in **Users** table.

Query for creating the view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_view AS SELECT u.id, u.name,  GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill) as 
skills FROM users u, skills s WHERE u.id = s.user_id GROUP BY u.id
```

Now the problem is the created view is having only 2 rows,I know its because there is no value in the skills table for **user_id 3**. Now what I want is to have all the 3 rows with **Tony's** skill as **Null** value, like this:

```
+---------+------+-----------------+
| user_id | name | skills          |
+---------+------+-----------------+
| 1       | Joy  | PHP,CSS         |
+---------+------+-----------------+
| 2       | Roy  | Ruby,Javascript |
+---------+------+-----------------+
| 3       | Tony | Null or empty   |
+---------+------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Left join`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_view AS
    SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill) AS skills
    FROM
        users u
            LEFT JOIN
        skills s ON u.id = s.user_id
    GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Thanks, this works :). Is that because  I'm not using the **LEFT JOIN** ? And also the i think the `SEPARATOR` is not mandotary.

Comment: Yes, your join was inner join and yes, `separator` clause is not mandatory but helps you want some other character as separator.

Comment: Of course.. Sorry for late voting :P. I was testing this code myself according to my requirement. Thank you.